# Elasticsearch: how to to calculate avg _score on each bucket?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have a match query and I want to do a terms aggregation (say on field doctype) to calculate on each bucket the average _score of the query. I don't find how to access the _score field within the aggregation.
Someone can help?
thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access score you would need to have scripting enabled.
Then you can access the [score in document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_accessing_the_score_of_a_document_within_a_script) as shown in example below:

```
"aggs": {
      "type_bucket": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_type"
         },
        "aggs": {
            "avg_score": {
                "avg": {
                    "script": "_score"
                }
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you keety, my error was to put "field": "_score" instead of "script": "_score"